# "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number" PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this query

```
$selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM daily_table WHERE date = :date AND event_type = :event_type AND product_type = :product_type";

$selectStatement = $db ->prepareQuery($selectQuery);
```

and I need to execute this inside a loop like

```
foreach ($tokenActivity as $activity) {

    $tokenActivityData = array(
                            "date"=>$activity['activity_date'],
                            "event_type"=>$activity['event_type'],
                            "product_type"=>$activity['product_type']
                         );

    $dataExists = $selectStatement->executeQuery($tokenActivityData);

    var_dump($dataExists);
}
```

Now this is giving me the error

```
string(41) "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number"
```

executeQuery is my wrapper function and it contains

```
//execute the statement
public function executeQuery($values) 
{
    try {

        if(empty($values)) {
            $res = $this->stmnt->execute(); 
        } else {
            $res = $this->stmnt->execute($values);
        }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $res;
}
```

Comment: Comparing your code with the examples (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and assuming the variables are well set, the keys of $tokenActivityData should have exactly the same name in the query.

Comment: They are same right ?

Comment: I have user : also. But it also showing the same error

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that while using `execute` method the way you use it `All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR`. Maybe it has something to do with that. Try to use `bindValue`.

Comment: The keys in $tokenActivityData should be like ':date', ':event_type', ':product_type'. If it does not work, can you show the code of function prepareQuery ?